# How to save file in HTML FileSystem API using mt-downloader?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-filesystem

I am using mt-downloader to download and save files from server. It works fine when i save the file in system filesystem like
    `/var/datafiles/filename.ext`
But i am getting error when i try to save the file using HTML Filesystem API. It says
    `Error: Invalid File Path`

Answer (score 0):

Go with 
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

the HTML Filesystem API is still not standart